# Custom video buffering from remote https url

Tags: javascript, react-native, ffmpeg

In the abstract, how does video buffering work? Say I have a video file on a remote server that I want to download to a device and play, is there any way I could implement a custom buffering algorithm with just an https url?

I've been googling it and can't find anything technical on video buffering, I would assume most video players have a buffering algorithm built in but I'm not using a video player on this particular project.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The question is too vague. You need to be more specific on your input and output

Comment: "how does video buffering work" seemed pretty specific to me. I've been doing research on this and I'm pretty certain that it's just an http stream that returns the data in chunks as it's retrieved from the server. Unfortunately there's no http stream api implementation in react native right now and potentially due to technical limitations with sending data from native to javascript

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12912 I'm considering trying my hand at building out a streaming api implementation but I have no idea what scope or complexity that would take. I've been digging into the source code of react-native-video to see how it's buffering works and I might opt for a native buffering solution similar to react-native-videos's that I can wrap and use in javascript